# Python Decorators on Class Level Variables as Metadata for Reflection?

Tags: python, reflection, decorator, python-decorators

I have a python class (actually its a Google App Engine model) which looks like this:

```
class MyClass(ParentClass):
    variable_one = PropertyClass(...)
    variable_two = PropertyClass(...)
```

I intend to build a system which can describe the difference between two instances of this class that represent two versions of the entity at different points in time. Ultimately it would produce a string like

```
"Variable One changed from 'foo' to 'bar', Variable Two changed from empty to 'baz'"
```

So, I need to somewhere to store the fact that "variable_one" should be displayed as "Variable One" and so on. Coming from a C# background, my instinct is to use Attributes, for example:

```
class MyClass : ParentClass
{
    [DisplayName("Variable One")]
    public PropertyClass variable_one;

    [DisplayName("Variable Two")]
    public PropertyClass variable_two;
}
```

At first, the python equivalent appears to be decorators:

```
class MyClass(ParentClass):
    @display_name("Variable One")
    variable_one = PropertyClass(...)

    @display_name("Variable Two")
    variable_two = PropertyClass(...)
```

However, decorators are really doing function currying and as the class variable definition is just assigning an instance of the PropertyClass to variable_one and variable_two it doesn't look like that would be valid python. In any case, I'm not sure how I'd write that.

One option appears to be to extend the PropertyClass...

```
class MyClass(ParentClass):
    variable_one = MyPropertyClass("Variable One", ...)
    variable_two = MyPropertyClass("Variable Two", ...)
```

But there are a few different property classes being used and I want to add one common behaviour to all of them so this seems like too much effort.

I guess I could define a dictionary:

```
class MyClass(ParentClass):
    variable_one = PropertyClass(...)
    variable_two = PropertyClass(...)
    variable_display_names = {
        "variable_one": "Variable One",
        "variable_two": "Variable Two"
    }
```

But I'm hoping to hear from some more experienced pythoners about the best most pythonic way of achieving this.

Comment: You say that extending `PropertyClass` is an issue due to adding behaviour to all of the classes - but that's easily done, just add a single base class. Hell, even if that isn't possible, you could even monkey patch it in.

Comment: I love a good monkey patch!

Comment: Is there a reason why you would prefer 'Variable_one changed from ...' rather than 'variable_one ...' = why do you want to display another name than tha original? have you looked into the dir() function? or MyClass.__dict__ ?

Comment: @Lattyware I don't have access to the various property classes as they're the google app engine property classes, so the only way I could think of doing it would be to derive from each one.

Comment: @User because this string will be shown to the users but the internal names for the variables might be a little too technical

Comment: @mgilson: No need to monkeypatch anything here..

Comment: @Lattyware: The property classes are provided by Google's app engine libraries, so providing a new base class is going to be.. tricky to maintain. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I had a feeling that something like that would be the solution, but since I don't know anything about google's app engine libraries I figured that I'd not guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The datastore Property classes are descriptors (like the python `@property` decorator), but as custom classes that do not implement `__setattr__` you can set arbitrary attributes on those objects:

```
 class MyClass(ParentClass):
     variable_one = PropertyClass(...)
     variable_one.display_name = "Variable One"

     variable_two = PropertyClass(...)
     variable_two.display_name = "Variable Two"
```

which can be generalized to a decorator with:

```
def display_name(dispname):
    def decorate_with_display_name(prop):
        prop.display_name = dispname
        return prop
    return decorate_with_display_name
```

As long as you access the Property via the class (and not the instance) you can retrieve those values again; given an instance you can do `print type(instance).variable_two.display_name`, for example.